# Mock a PyQt Method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pyqt5

I have an existing class which inherits from the PyQT5 classes QWidget and Ui_Dialog.

I want to use some functionality of the class which is not at all related to the GUI. I have therefore tried to mock out the relevant bits, such as the `__init__` function which has a lot of GUI-specific code. There is also a specific method in the class which needs overriding (`_getSqlQuery`).

```
class TestPyQgs(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_comment_parsing(self):
    query = "SELECT * FROM test"
    with patch.object(DlgSqlWindow, "__init__", lambda x, y, z: None):
      with patch.object(DlgSqlWindow, "_getSqlQuery", return_value=query):
        a = DlgSqlWindow(None,None)
        self.assertEqual(a.parseSQL(), query)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because anything that inherits from QtWidget (as DlgSqlWindow does) has to call init on the Base Class, so I get `super-class __init__() of type DlgSqlWindow was never called`. Is there no sane way of doing this? Otherwise  should I try and refactor the code to split GUI from functionality, or do a unit test on the GUI as well, which I would rather not do as I want the unit test to be as tight as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to just call the super QWidget who doesn't have much logic:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog):
        pass


class DlgSqlWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Dialog):
    def _getSqlQuery(self):
        pass

    def parseSQL(self):
        return "SELECT * FROM test"


def init(self, *args):
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
    # self.setupUi(self)


class TestPyQgs(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_comment_parsing(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        query = "SELECT * FROM test"
        with patch.object(DlgSqlWindow, "__init__", init):
            with patch.object(DlgSqlWindow, "_getSqlQuery", return_value=query):
                a = DlgSqlWindow(None, None)
                self.assertEqual(a.parseSQL(), query)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

But as you point out, the optimal solution is to refactor your code since it seems that you are mixing business logic with the GUI which, as you can see, causes several inconveniences and is not maintainable.